# Comparing the elements within the Object

Tags: java, collections, comparable

When we compare the elements within the single `Collection` Object do we always need to override `equals` method? If yes why should we do that.

Actually we are comparing the elements through the `CompareTo` method by the integer as `1,0,-1` with their return types.

Comment: Note also that using the documentation for Comparable.compareTo method doesn't specify that the return value is 1, 0 or -1.    "Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.". So depending on what elements you have in your collection you might not get -1 or 1 for elements less than or greater than the object comparing to. For instance if you have Strings in your collection it's not always true that they return -1 or 1. E.g. "A^3k".compareTo("snOSyqJmbg") gives -50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we compare the elements within the single Collection Object do we always need to override equals method?

No.  You do not *have to* override `equals(Object)` in the general case.  For your particular application, it *may* be appropriate / necessary to override equals (and hashcode), but that depends on what the non-overridden version of the method does, and what behaviour your application needs.

> Actually we are comparing the elements through the CompareTo method by the integer as 1,0,-1 with their return types.

If you are using a Collection class that uses `compareTo` or `compare` rather than `equals`, then you clearly don't *have to* override `equals`.  However, it is good practice for a classes `equals` and `compareTo` methods to be consistent.  A future developer might assume they are consistent and get a nasty surprise when they are not.  (Of course, there may be pragmatic reasons for inconsistency ... but you shouldn't let the methods be inconsistent out of laziness.)

Answer (score 2):

If using a set, Java will use the `equals()` method to compare the objects. If you are using a sorted collection, then the `Comparable` interface must be implemented.

By default the `equals()` will be true if the two object instances are the same, if you want implement more logic into the comparison, then you must implement the given method.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not override the equals method in your class, then the super class' (typically `java.lang.Object`) method will be called. If this is what you want, then you don't need to override `equals`.

Now, what `Object.equals()` [does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is probably not what you want:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

For example, `Integer` does override the equals method, so this works:

```
Integer a = new Integer(3);
Integer b = new Integer(3);
assert(a.equals(b)); //Succeeds
```

If it didn't, then a wouldn't equal b (according to Object.equals). So, it depends on what you need to do. Most Java standard classes will already have a proper equals method, and you don't need to override it. Your custom made classes, however, will default to Object.equals() and that will check if the objects are the same object (the same instance, the same bunch of bytes in memory) and that's typically not what you want.

Also, notice that a HashMap will not use equals for comparison, but rather hashCode, and that a TreeSet, for instance, will use the `Comparable` interface methods. Typically, if you override *equals*, don't forget to override *hashCode* at the same time (Eclipse has good auto-generated options if you prefer).

Comment: When you will be implement you own `equal` method, you have to implement `hashcode` method too. its work together.

Comment: Technically it doesn't, but it's a good practice. The reason is that equality in e.g. an ArrayList is done with equals, while in a HashSet it's done with hashCode so, if you do one but not the other, and you get a "List" you have no idea how it will be compared

Answer (score 1):

The equals method does need to be overridden in order do to a more complex comparison then to only check if two instances are the same.

Say that you have a class Person, and you want Persons with the same social security number to be "equal" to eachother. Then a simple implementation could look like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this.getSocialSecurityNumber() == obj.getSocialSecurityNumber())
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

This would cause each Person object to be "equal" of they have the same socialsecuritynumber. Note that overriding equals is not nessecary unless you want a specific behaviour, like this example

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have implemented compareTo() method then you don't need to implement equals() anymore, as compareTo() itself checks equality.

and even if you have implemented equals() separately, compareTo() hides its implementation and  your objects will never be tested against equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes. We always need to override equals method.**

**For ex.** If you are adding **null** in collection, we can't use **compareTo** because it will throw **NullPointerException**. But, equals() won't throw **NullPointerException**.

It is safer to override equals() to avoid NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you are talking about `Comparable` interface which implementation strongly recommended to be consistent with object's `equals()` method, still not required.
[Comparable description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)